# Translating "mankind evolves" and two other two-word phrases

Tags: translation-check, conjugation, english-to-latin-translation, noun

Are you willing to take a look at my efforts at translating 6 words from English to Latin?

Here goes:

Mankind evolves: *Homines evolvant*

God disappoints: *Deus frustrat*

Reason refutes: *Ratio refellat*

Thoughts? How did I do? I'm open to corrections.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Can you please specify what exactly you are not sure about in the above phrases? Our site format works best with specific questions.

Comment: brianpck, I'm a novice to Latin translation, so I'm looking for any and all commentary, but my primary question is about the conjugation. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

For the first one, you could also go with *mundus* for "mankind", since *homines* generally refers to a large group of people as opposed to an entity.
EDIT: *Evolvant* comes from *evolvo*, which is a third conjugation verb. Thus, *evolvant* is in the subjunctive mood as opposed to the indicative, *evolvunt*, which you should be using here.
*Evolvo* means "roll out" or "unfold", so I think *adveniunt* ("arrive at" or "reach"), or *augescunt* ("grow" or prosper" may better suit your translation. It all depends on the specific type of "evolution" you are talking about (ex: intellectual, physical, etc).
Also note that if you choose to go with *mundus*, you need a singular ending (*-t*) on the verb.

The second one looks good!

In the third phrase, alternate translations for "reason" are *mens* and *argumentum*, but *ratio* is perfectly acceptable too.
EDIT: Again, mind the conjugation. *Refellat* is the 3rd person active subjunctive of the word *refello*, so you should use *refellit* instead.

EDIT: Just a general note about verb conjugations:
Conjugations are determined by looking at the **2nd principal part** of the verb.

1st conjugation verbs end with *-āre*.

> *amō, am**āre**, amāvī, amātum* = love, like
>   *dō, d**āre**, dedī, datum* = give

2nd conjugation verbs end with *-ēre*.

> *videō, vid**ēre**, vidī, visum* = see, look at
>   *doceō, doc**ēre**, docuī, doctum* = to teach

3rd conjugation verbs end with *-ere*.

> *dicō, dic**ere**, dixī, dictum* = say, speak
>   *cadō, cad**ere**, cecidī, casum* = fall

4th conjugation verbs end with *-īre*.

> *dormiō, dorm**īre**, dormīvī, dormītum* = sleep, rest
>   *veniō, ven**īre**, venī, ventum* = come

The present stem of a verb is found by dropping the *-re* from the 2nd principal part for 1st and 2nd conjugation verbs, and by dropping the *-ō* from the 1st principal part for 3rd and 4th conjugation verbs. Once you obtain the stem, you can then add on the appropriate endings.

Hope this was helpful!

Comment: *evolvo* and *refello* are actually both 3rd conjugation, so they should be *evolvunt* and *refellit*. In addition, I do not think *confirmo* can be used intransitively in this way.

Comment: Ah yes, my apologies, I overlooked the conjugation of *evolvo* and *refello*. *Evolvant* would be a subjunctive meaning "they should evolve" as opposed to "they evolve", likewise with *refellat*. If you intend to use the present active forms, then the correct translations would be *evolvunt* and *refellit* as @brianpck mentioned.

Comment: This is valuable feedback, especially the conjugation help.

Comment: I have also received the suggestion that "Deus frustrat" should actually be "Deus frustratur" because "frustror" is a deponent verb. Thoughts?

Comment: According to Whitaker's Words, *frustrat* comes from *frustro, frustrare, frustravi, frustratus* which is active. Thus, *deus frustrat* would be correct.

Comment: @C.Torres-George It can be deponent and non-deponent, though Lewis & Short lists the deponent form as the "main" entry.

Comment: Holy moly! There is so much to learn about this language!

Comment: So, if it were deponent, would that make "Deus frustratur" the best translation?

Comment: @Sapphira Perhaps you can amend your answer with some of the suggestions here: as it stands I unfortunately can't upvote because it contains some erroneous forms.

Comment: I have used the suggestions to amend my answer, please let me know if there is anything else I need to mention! @brianpck

Answer (score 4):

The verb *evolvere* means to "roll out", "develop" or "evolve".
If you write *homines evolvunt*, I interpret it as "people develop [something]".
If mankind is the thing being developed rather than the one guiding the development, I would use passive.
To me, at least, *homines evolvuntur* means "people are developed" or "people evolve".
The verb *evolvere* is third conjugation, so I would read *homines evolvant* (which is conjunctive instead of indicative) as "may people develop [something]".

*Homines* means "people", not really "mankind".
*Genus humanum* would be more appropriate for "mankind" or "human race".
Note that it is singular, whereas *homines* is plural.
Thus I suggest: ***Genus humanum evolvitur.***

The second phrase is trickier.
I am not sure how to use the verbs *frustrare* and *frustrari*.
Instead, I suggest [*fallere*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dfallo), which is more severe than to "disappoint".
It also has this meaning, but it takes a step in the direction of deception, cheating, and dishonesty.
If this tone is acceptable, I suggest: ***Deus fallit.***

In the third phrase *ratio* sounds like a suitable word.
[*Refellere*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=refello&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059) and [*refutare*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=refuto&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059) are good verbs.
These are of the third and first conjugation, respectively.
Your *refellat* is conjunctive, and I assume that would give the wrong tone.
Using these, I suggest: ***Ratio refutat.***
Or: ***Ratio refellit.***

Comment: "People [themselves] evolve" is definitely the sense I intend, rather than "people develop/evolve [something]." "Fallere" is good to know, though the tone is probably not quite right for my current needs. And "Ratio refellit" seems to be have a consensus, so far. Thank you, Joonas Ilmavirta!

Comment: Great suggestions: *homo* (in the singular) might also be a good substitute for *genus humanum*, e.g. one of my favorite quotes: "homo sum et nihil humanum alienum a me esse puto"